# 'Unexpected token' in AJAX upload of multipart/form-data in angular.js 1.3.0

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

The following code for texture upload was working in angularjs 1.2.26 but stopped working when I upgraded my web application to 1.3.0.

HTML Code

```
<input file-model="file" name="file" type="file">
```

fileModel Directive

```
app.directive('fileModel', [ '$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });

            scope.$on("reset", function() {
                element.val(null);
            });

        }
    };
} ]);
```

Upload Function - In 1.2.26 choosing "multipart/form-data" as Content-Type would not work. But with "undefined" as Content-Type angular would do some kind of magic that would make it work.

```
var upload = function(textureUploadUrl) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', $scope.name);
        formData.append('file', $scope.file);

        $http.post(textureUploadUrl, formData, {
            transformRequest : angular.identity,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
            }
        }).success(function(uploadedTexture) {
            console.log(uploadedTexture);

            // further processing of uploadedTexture
        });
}
```

ERROR:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token h
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:1104:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:8572:18)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:8517:12
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:335:20)
    at transformData (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:8516:3)
    at transformResponse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:9224:23)
    at processQueue (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:12914:27)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:12930:27
    at Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js:14123:28)
```

Does anyone know how to get this working in the new version?

**UPDATE**

I've narrowed down the problem a little bit. It does not work with 1.3.0-rc.5, but with the previous version (rc.4) it does work. So, I'm currently trying to figure out which changes lead to my problem. Here is the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was in the response header of my texture upload request on server side. For building my application I used Spring MVC and had a request mapping like that, but without the `produces` specification:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public String textureUploadPOST(HttpServletRequest req) {
    // upload texture and create serveUrl for the texture
    return serveUrl;
}
```

So, without specifying `text/plain` as Content-Type, Spring automatically uses `application/json` as Content-Type. And this causes angular.js to invoke JSON.parse since 1.3.0-rc.5 ([change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7b6c1d08aceba6704a40302f373400aed9ed0e0b)). My texture upload returns an URL pointing to the location where the image is served. Because this is a plain String, it resulted in the described error message. So, don't forget to specify correct Content-Types in your server responses :-)

Comment: +1. I had excatly the scenario (file upload returning url) but with jersey instead of spring MVC. The same solution works, i annotate my resource with the jersey equivalent: `@Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)`. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Glad to hear that! At first I thought it had to do with the upload itself, but it turned out it was a problem with the response.

Comment: Note that the problem appears when i upgrade from angular 1.2 to 1.3.